# Silex Routing with wildcard throws error 500

Tags: php, twig, silex

I've just noticed that when there is a wrong URL like : http://example.com/articles/qslkdqm ; the controller throws an error 500 instead of an error 404.

So, I tried to manually change the StatusCode when the controller checks the slug to retrieve the data :

**Controller**

```
$article = $app['dao.article']->getArticle($slug); 
if (!$article) {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(404);
}
```

But it doesn't work and still throws an error 500.

Is that normal? We fully agree that this should be a 404?

I understand that it throws an error 500 because some variables are not defined (ie. the title of the article). Does that mean that in each variable call, I just check for its existence like:

```
{% if title is defined %}
...
{% endif %}
```

?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If there's a risk that they might not be defined, then yes. Alternatively, you could send default values if you're going to show the view without having any real values. It seems like you already know why you get a 500 error instead of a 404 (if there is a php-error (500), you can't override the http code with php, since it means that the php-parser can't parse the code.)

Comment: which is the error related to the 500? which message do you see? (on screen, logs, ...)

Comment: Thank you for your help @MagnusEriksson but the answer below solved it without having to declare default values.

Comment: @Matteo It shows errors about the variables that are not found (declared in my Twig templates : article title, content, meta etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can stop application with 404 error this way:

```
if (!$article) {
    $app->abort(404);
}
```

or

```
if (!$article) {
    throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException(404);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!